# How to simulate the distribution of a diagnostic test

Tags: r, distributions, simulation, beta-distribution, sensitivity-specificity

I have a parameter described as `mean (95% CI low-hi)` and would like to build a distribution that will have approximately that mean and lower/upper bounds. The constraints are that these are usually non-normal and all values have to be between 0 and 1. How would I go about that?

One brute-force method I thought about is below, but I was wondering if there is a *proper* or, at least, more *elegant* way to do this.

Note: A previous version of this question mentioned that these parameters are diagnostic test characteristics such as sensitivity and specificity.

```
bMoms <- function(m, sd) {
  ## the moments of the beta distribution   
  v <- sd^2
  t <- (1 - m)/v
  a <- m^2 * t
  b <- m * t - a
  ## method of moments
  t. <- m * (1 - m)/v - 1
  a. <- m * t.
  b. <- (1 - m) * t.
  return(c(a, b, a., b.))
}
m = (lo + 4 * m + hi)/6
m. <- (m - lo)/(hi - lo)  #normalize m to scale 0-1
sd. <- 1/6
ab <- bMoms(m., sd.)  # the moments of the beta distribution
df. <- data.frame(x = rbeta(n, ab[1], ab[2]))
df. <- within(df., x <- lo + x * (hi - lo))
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "Sens", "Sp", and "Se".

Comment: Sensitivity and specificity, but I re-phrased the question to be more general.

Comment: @koenbro A quick piece of advice: TPR and FPR are not Bayesian quantities. Their 95% CIs represent uncertainty in a study design, and ultimately shrink to zero-width as you conduct larger and larger studies. Still, they have no implication for individual outcomes.

Comment: @koenbro the clinical implications for the use and interpretation of the test come from the uncertainty in the *underlying prevalence of disease*. Here, Bayes rule (which is not inherently Bayesian statistics) helps clinicians understand and interpret findings better.

Comment: @AdamO Thank you for your comments.  I can of course calculate the LRN from sensitivity and specificity, but will the 95%CI of the LRN be? I was thinking of expressing both Se and Sp as distributions, sample them repeatedly and thus obtain the CI for the LRN. Further, as I use Bayes' rule (with, say, a 1% pretest prob of disease), how can I carry-over and express the uncertainty of the post test probability?

Comment: @koenbro you would not simulate sensitivity and specificity as distributions. Rather, you simulate a log linear model structurally with a possibly random or fixed number of participants, a binomial disease process, then a two separate test processes that evaluate to TP or FN in the diseased and TN or FP in the healthy. Setting TP/FN/FP/TN and P allows you to achieve any sensitivity/specificity for any disease probability.

Comment: @AdamO thanks, first off, for helping me clarify my question and second for your response. Can you point me to any example for this, that I can follow step by step?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70250/discussion-between-koenbro-and-adamo).

Comment: @AdamO why not expand your comments, especially the last one, into an answer?

Comment: What is the acronym "pd"in the code stand for? Can anyone please tell.

Comment: pd = probability of a positive diagnosis, I think. (e.g., no. diagnosed+ / n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simulation is a viable means of inspecting the operating characteristics of a diagnostic test. While preliminary studies present sensitivity and specificity with 95% confidence intervals, these CIs do not actually represent a Bayesian probability in what such values are. Thus when you set out to conduct your simulation study, it is better to consider the test characteristics as fixed or given, and then to simulate a random process of the disease status and test evaluation according to those parameters. By doing this, you can appropriately summarize the test performance (and its uncertainty) in a variety of scenarios, such as an elevated prevalence of disease or in larger samples. The basic parameters are given as follows:

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
 & D & \bar{D} & \\ \hline
T & TP & FP& n_t\\
\bar{T} & FN & TN & n-n_t\\
 & n_d & n-n_d
\end{array}

As an example, suppose a test was developed and studied in a cohort with 40% sensitivity ($TP/n_d$) and 90% specificity ($TN/(n-n_d)$). Suppose further I consult the literature and find that the originating sample was 100 patients with a disease prevalence of 10% (say, in a hospital setting). Then, the table above boils down to

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
 & D & \bar{D} & \\ \hline
T & 4 & 9 & 13\\
\bar{T} & 6 & 81 & 87\\
 & 10 & 90
\end{array}

But if we wish to simulate these outcomes, the $TN$ and the $FN$ are merely binomial probability models. Using R I can simulate this contingency table with:

```
sim <- function(n, pd, se, sp) {
  nd <- rbinom(1, n, pd)
  tp <- rbinom(1, nd, se)
  tn <- rbinom(1, n-nd, sp)
  matrix(c(tp, nd-tp, n-nd-tn, tn), 2, 2)
}
set.seed(123)
sim(n=100, pd=0.1, se=0.4, sp=0.9)
```

gets:

```
> sim(n=100, pd=0.1, se=0.4, sp=0.9)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    8
[2,]    4   84
```

which shows some stochastic variability from the design. Performing many 1000s of replications:

```
OUT <- replicate(1000, sim(n=100, pd=0.1, se=0.4, sp=0.9))
sens <- OUT[1,1,] / colSums(OUT[,1,])
mean(sens) + c('lower 95%'=-1, 'mean'=0, 'upper 95%'=1) %o%  qnorm(0.975) * sd(sens)
```

Which gives

```
> mean(sens) + c('lower 95%'=-1, 'mean'=0, 'upper 95%'=1) %o%  qnorm(0.975) * sd(sens) 
                [,1]
lower 95% 0.06350984
mean      0.40045478
upper 95% 0.73739973
```

So as expected this design is inefficient for evaluating test-reliability. We did not generate variability in the test, but rather simulated the test outcome as a random process which is accurately summarized in the sensitivity and specificity and varies under experimentation a function of experimental design.

Comment: I would like to publish some work using this approach in a medical journal. Is there an academic reference I can cite for this approach? Would "Efron & Tibshirani 1994 An introduction to the bootstrap" be appropriate?

Comment: For anyone else wondering,  I _think_ a suitable reference would be "Mossman, D., & Berger, J. O. (2001). Intervals for posttest probabilities: a comparison of 5 methods. Medical Decision Making, 21(6), 498-507.", which describes an objective Bayesian method to obtain the same credible intervals.